# C++ coding in eclipse...help with code assist

Tags: c++, eclipse

How can i get C++ coding in eclipse to act like coding in java?

In java, i can nicely add external jar files and the code assist can nicely suggest methods or suggest adding unimplemented methods for interfaces.

But in C++ mode, it doesn't seem to work when i include external header files. What else should i try?

Comment: Yes using CDT. somehow its not as intuitive and intelligent as coding for java in terms of autocomplete, code assist...but it migbt be my settings

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT itself does not come with any compilers/libraries therefore you need to select and install a toolchain. There are a few options for this

- Visual Studio (cl)
- MinGW (g++)
- Cygwin (g++)

Note, you can get VS Express for free and if you are a student can even get the professional version from [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/)

Once you have installed any of these you can select them as the toolchain for your C/C++ projects, this will enable you to build your projects nicely from within eclipse.

Also, you may need to point eclipse to the library files used by your compiler, for instance I use the VS2010 toolchain under Eclipse CDT so I must add

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"
```

to the include directories in build settings.

**Edit:** Sorry if it wasn't clear, once you've done this code completion should work for your C/C++ projects.